# Complex Conjugate of a Complex-Valued Function

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a process that could be used to find the complex conjugate of a complex-valued function *f*(*x*), or can the complex conjugate only be found once a value has been inputted for the '*x*' variable?

Comment: It mostly depends on what the rule of you $f(x)$ is. Do you have a particular $f$ you are interested in?

Comment: Well, complex conjugation is a function, you can denote it $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $g(x+iy)=x-iy$, and the complex conjugate of $f$ is the composed function $g \circ f$.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Yes, but it is a very very long, multivariable function, haha. I'm guessing it would be quite difficult to find the complex conjugate in this specific case, without a general rule?

Comment: @sworCFan generally you just have to see if your particular "subfunctions" can be written in a way that the real part and complex part can be separated easily. For your case, I'm afraid not...

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Oh well, thanks anyway!